# C# winrt scale and translate ellipse

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, zooming, scale, translate

I develop in C# with Windows runtime. I have an image with scrollviewer. On this image, i make dynamically ellipses. When i zoom image, ellipses don't zoom. I want to know how can i zoom ellipse to keep the good position.

My code :

```
List<Point> pTmp = new List<Point>();
Point positionOrigine = new Point();

if(tabPointOrig == null)
{
    tabPointOrig = new List<Point>();
    tabPointOrig = tabPoint;
}

foreach(Point p in tabPointOrig)
{
    pTmp.Add(new Point(
        Math.Round(p.X - Scroll.HorizontalOffset),
        Math.Round(p.Y - Scroll.VerticalOffset)));
}

tabPoint = pTmp;

foreach(var Can in GridImage.Children)
{
    if(Can.GetType() == typeof(Canvas))
    {
        Canvas CanTmp = (Canvas)Can;

        foreach (var CanElement in CanTmp.Children)
        {
            TransformGroup TG = new TransformGroup();
            TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
            ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform();

            positionOrigine = new Point(
                Canvas.GetLeft(CanElement),
                Canvas.GetTop(CanElement));

            #region Deplacement des point
            //On deplace les points de réserve en même temps que l'image
            trans.X = Scroll.HorizontalOffset * -1;
            trans.Y = Scroll.VerticalOffset * -1;
            #endregion

            #region Zoom des points
            //On zoom les points de réserve en même temps que l'image
            ZoomFactor = Scroll.ZoomFactor;
            scale.ScaleX = scale.ScaleY = scale.ScaleX * ZoomFactor;
            #endregion

            TG.Children.Add(scale);
            TG.Children.Add(trans);

            //On applique les changements a l'image
            CanElement.RenderTransform = TG;

            #region Point Sorti du Grid
            //On regarde si le point sort du grid
            if ((Canvas.GetLeft(CanElement) + trans.X + (30 * ZoomFactor)) < 0 ||
                (Canvas.GetTop(CanElement) + trans.Y + (30 * ZoomFactor)) < 0
                )
                Can.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                Can.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "good position"? Could you draw two pictures of before and after view of what you want to achieve? What's the visual tree that you are using? Is the code you shared something you run in a `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` event handler?

Comment: Yes it is the code which is shared when i run in ScrollViewer.ViewChanged